# AS3 TextField AntiAliasType breaks WordWrap

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am dynamically creating and populating a TextField in AS3. I have embedded some fonts into my library (using Flash) and am setting the font of the text field using TextFormat. Because of the limited width of the TextField I have `textfield.multiline = true;` and `textfield.wordWrap = true;`, however I have noticed that the fonts look a little pixelated.

To fix this I am using `textfield.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;` which makes the text look nice, but stops the word-wrap from working. In fact it looks quite odd; The text keeps keeps going off the width of the TextField then puts the last word on a new line.

What do I need to do to make it look good and wrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical. Ask a question, find the answer =/

Specifying a grid fit type to the TextField fixes it. Don't know why:

`textfield.gridFitType = GridFitType.SUBPIXEL;`

From the [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/GridFitType.html):

> Fits strong horizontal and vertical
>   lines to the sub-pixel grid on LCD
>   monitors. (Red, green, and blue are
>   actual pixels on an LCD screen.) This
>   is often a good setting for
>   right-aligned or center-aligned
>   dynamic text, and it is sometimes a
>   useful tradeoff for animation vs. text
>   quality. This constant is used in
>   setting the gridFitType property of
>   the TextField class. Use the syntax
>   GridFitType.SUBPIXEL.

Comment: Please mark your answer as correct if it is a real solution. :)

Comment: I need to wait 24 hours after posting an answer to my own question before marking it as the answer. It is on my todo list