# Actionscript: input text on iOS working differently than in the simulator

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

I have an input box created in Flash Professional 500px x 500px, set as Classic Text > Input Text > Singleline.

I import this into my Actionscript project and set to

```
wordWrap = true;
```

In the simulator this works great.

However on iOS wordwrap does not occur during input. Everything appears on a single line which is in the center of the textbox height, when focus returns to the app the text is then correctly wrapped.

How can I make it work like it does in the simulator.

As a fix I tried using multiline text box.

This does not have the issue above, however it introduces a new issue, on selection of the textbox the cursor appears one line below the top, I have to press backspace to move to the top of the textbox, interestingly the text box has size 0 despite some sort of new line existing. This occurs in the simulator as well as on the device.

Comment: Explicitly set **.text = "";** after creation/instantiation.

Comment: I think I remember it has a default **htmlText** set to something like **<P ALIGN="LEFT"></P>** which results in the behavior you observe.

Comment: Thanks, I did already use text='' as a hack, it just seemed wrong to need to set it this way.

Comment: Have you read/try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793032/as3-textfield-antialiastype-breaks-wordwrap)?